# create-react-app clean urls with browserHistory

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, create-react-app

I have an app created with create-react-app boilerplate. I'm also using react router and I try to use browserHistory for clean links (no #). I follow this [lesson](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/10-clean-urls) but I fail to add `--history-api-fallback` to webpack dev server. I'm not familiar with devpack at all so I dont know where should I put this line so when I reload page I don't get 404 (it happens only when deploying build to server).

I already did `eject` with npm.

```
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, IndexRedirect, browserHistory} from 'react-router';

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
            ...
        </Router>
        , document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

**EDIT**

Reloads work without configuration when I run app locally or when I tried (as suggested) with `pushstate-server build`. It only doesn't work when I push build to my free web hosting at openshift.com (it was working with browserHash thought)